# How to create a unique id for a fingerprint template

Tags: vb.net, fingerprint

Can you give me some tips for creating a unique id for a fingerprint template.

I can save the template into a MySQL database using VB.NET and I can verify it.

The problem is the fingerprint template is saved as a blob. I have a table, `tbl_students`, into which the fingerprints and students info is stored and I want to fetch that info when fingerprint is verified.

Can you help me with this logic? My fingerprint device is `UareU 4500`.

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you're after. Are you seeking to identify a student based on their fingerprint? Or are you seeking to verify a student (ie you already know their student id)?

Comment: im a little confused. can you explain it both?

Comment: You say " i want to fetch that info when fingerprint is verified.". I'm trying to figure out what you mean with the verified part. Do you mean I want to fetch a student based on their fingerprint. Or do you mean, the student using the finger print reader has been verified as being student xxx and I want to grab his/her details from the table.

Comment: ah. got it. i want to fetch the student base on their fingerprint. in my case. im developing a student entry/exit monitoring system. i want to fetch those info when someone registered student tapped in the device. and then the system will show the student info(id number, image, firstname).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are fetching student data from your table, assuming you are doing verification in a loop, when a student's fingerprint template is correctly matched to fingerprint template from scanner, you return the student ID saved against that student's fingerprint template and with that student ID, you can use it to fetch from same SQL table to display particulars of verified student.